# calculate mean value for the missing values

Tags: python, missing-data, data-preprocessing

I need to calculate the mean of neighbor values to replace it with NaN value, but the problem is, I don't want to make my code more complicated.

For example,

[image]

I have there 20 countries and 4 car types from 2010 to 2020, but there are some missing values in the beginning or middle or end sometimes next two each other.

The solution came in my mind is that I slice the data and then replace the NaN with 3 neighbors before and after the missed valueS, but it is not always in the middle so there would be in beginning 3 missed values.

What is the best solution for the missing values?

Comment: Please post your table as text, not an image of text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample_date = { 'countries': ['USA','Canada','USA','UK','USA','UK','DE'],
                'car_type': ['sedan','sedan','Hatchback','coupe','sedan','coupe','coupe'],
                'years': [2010,2010,2011,2011,2017,2017,2010],
                'price': [4000,np.NaN,4000,4000,np.NaN,np.NaN,4000]}
data = pd.DataFrame(sample_date)

fillValue = 4000

data['price'].fillna(value=fillValue, inplace=True)
print('update Dataframe:')
print(data)
mean_value=data['price'].mean()

print(mean_value)
```

answer will be 4000 as I'm replacing NaN with neighbors as '4000'

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it's not possible to replace it by the general mean, for example in USA I have 4 car types and each car type has a period from 2010 to 2020, so the missing value should be replaced by the mean of the specific category, but it not good to calculate the mean value of the whole values in that specified column. so I need to replace it by mean of the 3 or 4 neighbors.